# How to loop through a table and get the td elements to follow a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, html-table

I just want make so it the `tr` hides when the `td` does not follow the requirements, tried with jQuery and JavaScript, don't know what's wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("price_search");
        if (id > value4 && id < value5) {
            $(this).hide;
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide;
        }
    });         
});
```

Comment: `value4  value5` where are these variables?

Comment: Can u provide more code ? I dont get what is value4 value5

Comment: Please add the HTM and the other variables so we might better assist you.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and missing JS (the values) to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: And if you want to hide the tr u need to adress it.

`$(this).parent("tr").hide();`

Comment: Apart from anything else, `$(this).hide()` is a method of the jQuery Object, the parentheses are necessary. Without them all you're getting  is the function code held in that property-value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

Hope this will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value4 = 2;
  var value5 = 4;
  $("td").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("price_search");
    if (id > value4 && id < value5) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td price_search="3">10</td>
    <td price_search="2">20</td>
    <td price_search="3">30</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb here and make broad assumptions on content not in the question.

Your `.hide;` is invalid syntax

You are missing value for two variables `value4` and `value4` which frankly are not well named variables at all.  I will make an assumption that those are better named and that they come from somewhere during the page rendering.

I make an assumption that you have something you want to filter/hide by those upper/lower price points.

I make the assumption the attribute might contain values that need to be parsed (not a number as they are)

```js
var lowerPricePoint = .45;
var upperPricePoint = 5.25;
$(function() {
  $("td").filter('[price_search]').each(function() {
    // parse out a price from perhaps formatted values
    let price = Number.parseFloat($(this).attr("price_search").replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    // toggle visibility of the row
    $(this).closest('tr').toggle(price > lowerPricePoint && price < upperPricePoint);
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Wear it</td>
    <td price_search="123.13">Shoes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Drive it</td>
    <td price_search="$23,123.13">Car</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Drink it</td>
    <td price_search="3.13">Beet Juice</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eat it</td>
    <td price_search="12.13">Can of expensive corn</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cheap</td>
    <td price_search="35">Radish</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Use it</td>
    <td price_search="1.45">Paper towel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Plain</td>
    <td price_search="$1.87">Butter</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Herb</td>
    <td price_search="$2.45">Butter</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cheap</td>
    <td price_search="15">Gum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```